# EntityFramework does not find connection string that is present when called in unit test

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nunit, .net-4.7.2

I am encountering the following error in an nunit test as soon as the model calls the database for the first time.

> System.InvalidOperationException: No connection string named
>   'OilModel' could be found in the application config file.    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ConnectionHasModel()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType)

App config has the following connection string added by the wizard.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="OilModel" connectionString="metadata=res://*/OilModel.csdl|res://*/OilModel.ssdl|res://*/OilModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=abcd.database.windows.net;initial catalog=volumetric_reporting;persist security info=True;user id=foo;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Reinstalling Entity Framework and recreating the model does not fix the error.

Why can't entity framework find the connection string?

Comment: Make sure all your projects that use any other project that uses Entity Framework are also referencing EF and also have that connection string. So if `ProjA` is your DB access and `ProjB` uses `ProjA`, `ProjB` also needs to reference EF and have the connection string. **Edit**: Not sure if EF reference is needed, but the connection string in App.config is

Comment: is the config file located at the startUp project?

Comment: Do you have a separate app config maybe from where you launch?

Comment: So the detail i forgot to add was that this failed from an nunit test project - didnt know it needed a separate app.config - worked with connection string and ef references Thanks!